# Mp3 player with GUI on Python

Tags: python, user-interface, module, mp3

I was wondering if the was an already built in plugin or module to use or do I have to create a GUI from start and use a music library ?
What I would need is to include an mp3 player inside my program ( not use an external one, I don't want to open another window ) and to control play , pause , volume , next song , prev song and time slide in the song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Music Player](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/musicplayer) provides a very simple demo with a GUI for a music player.  This can easily be extended to provide for more features.  The example given on the page linked is:

```
import musicplayer, sys, os, fnmatch, random, pprint, Tkinter

class Song:
        def __init__(self, fn):
                self.url = fn
                self.f = open(fn)
        # `__eq__` is used for the peek stream management
        def __eq__(self, other):
                return self.url == other.url
        # this is used by the player as the data interface
        def readPacket(self, bufSize):
                return self.f.read(bufSize)
        def seekRaw(self, offset, whence):
                r = self.f.seek(offset, whence)
                return self.f.tell()

files = []
def getFiles(path):
        for f in sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda k: random.random()):
                f = os.path.join(path, f)
                if os.path.isdir(f): getFiles(f) # recurse
                if len(files) > 1000: break # break if we have enough
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.mp3'): files.append(f)
getFiles(os.path.expanduser("~/Music"))
random.shuffle(files) # shuffle some more

i = 0

def songs():
        global i, files
        while True:
                yield Song(files[i])
                i += 1
                if i >= len(files): i = 0

def peekSongs(n):
        nexti = i + 1
        if nexti >= len(files): nexti = 0
        return map(Song, (files[nexti:] + files[:nexti])[:n])

# Create our Music Player.
player = musicplayer.createPlayer()
player.outSamplerate = 96000 # support high quality :)
player.queue = songs()
player.peekQueue = peekSongs

# Setup a simple GUI.
window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Music Player")
songLabel = Tkinter.StringVar()

def onSongChange(**kwargs): songLabel.set(pprint.pformat(player.curSongMetadata))
def cmdPlayPause(*args): player.playing = not player.playing
def cmdNext(*args): player.nextSong()

Tkinter.Label(window, textvariable=songLabel).pack()
Tkinter.Button(window, text="Play/Pause", command=cmdPlayPause).pack()
Tkinter.Button(window, text="Next", command=cmdNext).pack()

player.onSongChange = onSongChange
player.playing = True # start playing
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There won't be a conflict if I use two different GUI toolkits ?

Comment: @Nisman If you use another GUI toolkit to TKinter, the sample code posted above will be problematic.  However, this is just an example and you can extend it easily to another GUI.  Simply, all you need to have on your GUI is a button which calls "cmdPlayPause" or "cmdNext" and a string that holds the value of the current song.